# How to know if alt key is pressed in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to do some thing when alt + r is pressed in ckeditor.This is my code

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(e) {
            e.editor.on('contentDom', function() {
                e.editor.document.on('keydown', function(evt) {
                    var code=evt.data.getKey();
                    if(code==82){
                        if (evt.data.altKey) {
                            alert('ALt + R pressed');
                        }
                    }

                });
            });
        });
```

on pressing r its returning 82 but `evt.data.altKey` its not working.

Comment: try `CKEDITOR.ALT` instead

Comment: not working . for now i am doing if code = 4456530

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
if (evt.data.getKeystroke() == 88) {//'put value of alt keystroke 88'
    console.log('Alt Key Pressed');
    //Your function call 
}
```